# Did Luke provide other writings under a different name?

Tags: luke

Luke was considered to be a prolific writer, but I cannnot find any other information on this aspect of his life.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).  For more on what this site is all about, please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). As you may be aware, the book of Acts is also traditionally attributed to Luke. However, the authorship of many of the books of the New Testament, not to mention many related extra-biblical books of the same general time period, is a matter of great scholarly debate.

Answer (score 1):

Luke's Gospel and Acts of the Apostles were originally anonymous until attributed to Paul's companion Luke, later in the second century. The author never claims to be Luke, but Irenaeus appears to have been the first to make that attribution.

As we do not know who really wrote Luke-Acts, we need not be surprised that we do not know any other books written by the same author. However, the author's skills in Greek rhetoric were not learnt overnight, so he must have written other works before undertaking these masterpieces. Perhaps one day, stylistic analysis of other extant late first-century or early second-century books could help identify previous works that might have been written by 'Luke', but that is a distant possibility at best.